# Getting a nasty route request loop in React Native development

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm developing with React Native and getting a nasty GET request loop on start up with `npm run ios:dev`

It looks like this:

[image]

I'm using XCode and metro - not Expo. I installed Pod in the `ios` folder. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Not quite helpful. Looks like some sort of API error? what is /users/me? Is it a API endpoint that you integrated in the app?

Answer (score 0):

**504 Gateway Timeout**

The 504 (Gateway Timeout) status code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from an upstream server it needed to access in order to complete the request

For detail you can see here [504-gateway-timeout-error](https://www.lifewire.com/504-gateway-timeout-error-explained-2622941)

Comment: So this might not be on my end? Adding to this situation, the API DID work before. I'm not sure if there's something on my end that I'm over looking or if I should reach out to the backend developer.

Comment: It's definitely not the backend. It's something local but haven't changed the code base.

Comment: It's not on the client-side of course, most of the time, a 504 Gateway Timeout error means that whatever other server is taking so long that it's "timing out," is probably down or not working properly.